# Listening to 80 port with non-root Glassfish on Centos

Tags: centos, port, glassfish, rbac, usermod

I use Glassfish Stack to manage applications. I run Glassfish on CentOS with non-root user. Therefor I am not able to open 80 port as the ports under 1024 are accessibly only by root users.

There is a solution to add privilege in role based access control (rbac) system to user which runs the glassfish server:

```
/usr/sbin/usermod -K defaultpriv=basic,net_privaddr *glassfish*
```

In CentOS the *usermod* command doesn't include the -K option to change the default privileges. However, the RBAC is supported in CentOS (as far as I understand). Is there any solution to give simple user access to network listening under 1024 port?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That RBAC command/privilege is Solaris specific.

Since you're using CentOS, I doubt you're using a new enough kernel (at least 2.6.24) that supports the cleanest solution which involves setpcap.  Using iptables to redirect port 80 might be your best bet.

For reference, see this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277991/how-can-i-run-a-server-on-linux-on-port-80-as-a-normal-user).